# Java error not a statement

Tags: java, string, try-catch

When I try to compile my code I get the message

```
Main.java:31: error: not a statement
String bed = f.split(" ")
```

and also

```
error: ';' expected
String bed = f.split(" ");
```

I don't understand what's going on. I need to assign part of a file to a string.

Here's the code :

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.*;

public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args){
    if ( args[0] == null){

        System.out.println("File not Found");
        return;
        }

    try {
        File driver = new File (args[0]);
         Scanner j = new Scanner( driver );
         int i = 0;
         while( j.hasNextLine()) {
            String f = j.nextLine();
            if (f.isEmpty() || f.startsWith("/")){   //If the String f is empty or has / it will continue reading the nextline after the / or space
                continue;
                if (f.startsWith("d")) {
                String d = f.split(" ");

            }
                if (f.startsWith("b")) {
                String b = f.split(" ");

                }

                if (f.startsWith("bed"))
                String bed = f.split(" ");
            }



            System.out.println(f);

         }

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());



    }

    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage);

    }



}
```

}

Comment: `.split` method returns an array so you should store it in an array, not in a string

Answer (score 4):

.split() method returns an array so you should store it in an array, not in a string. Your code should be `string b[]=f.split(" ")` rather than storing it in `string b`

Answer (score 3):

The split method returns splits the string based on the regex and returns an String array.

What you have here is  `String d = f.split(" ");`, here you are trying to assign a string array to a string, and that is wrong.

It should instead say  `String[] d = f.split(" ");`

Comment: @MiguelPinedo hope it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this error.
I found a solution like below.

Error code

```
String a = "I goto the school";
String [] b = a.split("\\\s"); // error not a statement
```

Run code

```
try
{
      String a = "I goto the school";
      String [] b = a.split("\\\s");
}
catch(exception e)
{

}
```